# Binary converting hex from unsigned char to int

Tags: c, binary

I might be asking a duplicate question but can't seem to find it.

How do I convert a hex say from  `1e` in an unsigned char  to   `0x1e` in an int (**not unsigned**)?

and to concatenate them i would need to

`hex3 = (hex1 << 8) | hex2;`

and if i wanted to do it over and over again could i do this?

`hex3 = (hex3 << 8) | hex2;`

sorry these might be really questions but i cant seem to get my head round binary operations :(

edit:
so.. can i do this?

```
int hex;
while (!feof(in))
{ 
   unsigned char input = fgetc(in);
  hex = hex + input;
};`
```

if the `input` was `1e` will the `hex` be `0x1e` and I later want to concatenate so if the next `input` was `ff` i would wan the output to be `0x1eff`

Comment: `unsigned char` is an integer type, just shorter (probably) than an int. You can just assign an unsigned char to an int. There is no problem unless `char` and `int` happen to be the same size and the value in the `char` is greater than `MAX_INT`; in practical terms, that will never happen.

Comment: So basically i can do this?
`unsigned char = hex,       
int hex1 = hex`

Comment: It would help if you put together an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It's not entirely clear what `hex1` and `hex2` represent.

Answer (score 0):

Some notes

1. You need to check the return value from `fgetc` to determine when the end-of-file has been reached. See [while-feof-file-is-always-wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5432517/3386109).
2. `fgetc` returns an `int` not a `char`. The reason is so that you can detect when `EOF` is returned.
3. You can only shift bytes into the `int` until the `int` is full. On a 32-bit system, an `int` is only 4 bytes, so you can only do this 4 times.
4. C doesn't have hex numbers and decimal numbers, it just has an `int` type that stores a number. The `printf` function can be used to display an `int` in hex or decimal. To display a number in decimal use `printf("%d",n)`, to display a number in hex use `printf("%x",n)`.

With that in mind, here's how I would write the code. (I'm assuming that an `int` is 4 bytes and the file has 4 or fewer bytes in it.)

```
int number = 0;
int c;
while ( (c = fgetc(in)) != EOF )
    number = (number << 8) | (c & 0xff);

printf( "%x\n", number );
```